# How can I get JSON data from Google API and store it in a variable?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api

I am trying to send an Http Get message to the Google location Api which is supposed to have Json data such as this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt
as you noticed the response is in Json. I want to give a a Http Call to that URL and save the Json content in a variable or string. My code does not give out any errors but it is also not returning anything

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> GetRequest()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await  client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt");
    string data = response.Content.ToString();
    return data;
}
```

I want to send out a Get Request using HttpClient() or anything that will send out the URL request and then save that content into a string variable . Any suggestions would be appreciated, again my code gives no errors but it is not returning anything.

Comment: What type of application is making the request?  This makes a big difference to the answer.

Comment: It is an MVC4 Application, I am basically making the call when the Controller Action gets submitted. I'll post more of the code above.

Comment: Follow the tree of the api, e.g to get long_name u need to write, results.adress_components.long_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ReadAsStringAsync to get the json response...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt");
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you use `response.Content.ToString()` it is actually converting the datatype of the Content to string so you will get `System.Net.Http.StreamContent`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt");
        string data = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Json framework](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for .NET powered by Newtonsoft ?
You can try to parse your content to a string with this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code can be simplified:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRequest()
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  return await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt");
}
```

However...

> My code does not give out any errors but it is also not returning anything

This is almost certainly due to using `Result` or `Wait` further up the call stack. [Blocking on asynchronous code like that causes a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog. The short version is that there is an ASP.NET request context that only permits one thread at a time; `await` by default will capture the current context and resume in that context; and since `Wait`/`Result` is blocking a thread *in* the request context, the `await` cannot resume executing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public async static Task<string> Something()
    {            
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los%20Angeles,CA=AIzaSyDABt";
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
            return result;
        }
        return "";
    }

var result = Task.Run(() => Something()).Result;
```